# Errors when installing udunits

Tags: compiling, cmake

I am trying to install udunits. I downloaded udunits-2.2.28.tar.gz from https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/service/rest/repository/browse/downloads-udunits/

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

First I installed cmake using:

```
version=3.19
build=1
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v$version/cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
tar -xzvf cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
cd cmake-$version.$build/
sudo apt install libssl-dev
./bootstrap
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install

cmake --version
Returns:
cmake version 3.19.6
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Then I navigated to the directory where I had unzipped the udunits file

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Downloads/udunits-2.2.28/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

This is what I am getting back:

```
DEFAULT_UDUNITS2_XML_PATH = "/mnt/c/Users/Downloads/udunits-2.2.28/../share/udunits/udunits2.xml"
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:132 (MESSAGE):
  makeinfo(1) not found.  Existing documentation will be used.


-- Unable to find CUnit library. Unit-testing not enabled.
CMake Error: File /mnt/c/Users/Downloads/udunits-2.2.28/config.h.cmake does not exist.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:206 (CONFIGURE_FILE):
  CONFIGURE_FILE Problem configuring file


Texinfo-file "udunits2lib.texi" will not be processed.
Texinfo-file "udunits2prog.texi" will not be processed.
Texinfo-file "udunits2.texi" will not be processed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Can anyone help? I have seen the topic here:

[Errors encountered while installing udunits library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943837/errors-encountered-while-installing-udunits-library)

but it doesn't help me proceed. I am very new to Ubuntu and it seems every time I get one thing fixed (a missing library or something) another error is thrown. I need to know if it is actually possible to install this library using Ubuntu. Has anyone done it?

Comment: Are you sure t works with Ubuntu?

Comment: Why are you trying to install it from source, instead of from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't realise there was another way. Is this it?https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libudunits2-dev

Comment: @David No, I am not.

Comment: @matlabcat that's the development package (and also for `bionic`, which is 18.04) - you can also install just the runtime library package `libudunits2-0` and/or the binary utilities package `udunits-bin`, depending on your requirements. You will need to enable the `universe` repository if you have not already done so then use `apt` to install the package(s).

Comment: @steeldriver You'll have to pardon my lack of knowledge here. Do you mean `sudo apt-get install libudunits2-0` and `sudo apt install udunits-bin'? I just need this because a package in R is dependent on it and am way out of my depth here!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to compile [packaged application](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/udunits), really.

Just open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev
```

and then use *udunits* in source (as build-time dependency) or binary form (`udunits2` executable from [*udunits-bin* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/udunits-bin/filelist)).